# 「行きと違い」 phrase meaning

Tags: grammar, translation

I completely cannot grasp the meaning of 行きと違い here:

> 夕食を終えた私は、なれない道に右往左往しながら寄宿舎へと向かっていた。行きと違い、友の案内がないだけで道を迷いそうになる。

"After I finished the dinner, I wandered an unfamiliar road to the dormitory. 行きと違い, without my friend's guidance I almost lost my way."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

違い is the 連用形 of 違う, comparable to 違って here.

Xと違う is "unlike X", "different from X".

And 行き is the opposite of 帰り, that is, "on the way there" as opposed to "on the way back" (presumably the character is currently on the way back). See [行き帰り](http://tangorin.com/general/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8D%E5%B8%B0%E3%82%8A).

Comment: Happy New Year :)